# Importar planilha excel com muitos registros com php

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Bom dia!!!
Eu tenho a seguinte situação, preciso fazer um import de planilha Excel (.xml).

Só que o problema é que a minha planilha tem mais de 100.000 registros e o php não consegue ler tudo.
O código está funcionando perfeitamente para planilha com 2500 registros.
Tem alguma forma que eu posso fazer pra ele ler os 100000?

Obg desde já.

Segue o código;

```
    $arquivo = new DOMDocument();
    $arquivo->load($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);

    $linhas = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Row");
  
    $listaArquivo = [];

    foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
       
        $listaTemp = [
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(0)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(1)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(2)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(3)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(4)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(5)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(6)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(7)->nodeValue,
            $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(8)->nodeValue
        ];

        array_push($listaArquivo, $listaTemp);

       // echo json_encode($listaTemp);
        
    }
   exit();
```

Answer (score -2):

Se o problema é o tempo de execução, e essa é uma operação única, ou seja, uma vez importada não será necessário ficar re-fazendo essa importação, você pode simplesmente aumentar o max_execution_time `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` 
ou `set_time_limit(300);`  que resolveria o problema.

Se vai ser feita uma importação constante, ou seja, essa funcionalidade é constantemente usada, você pode pensar em SPLITAR a operação em lotes menores, por exemplo de 2000 registros, e rodar ele de maneira parcial em sequencias te tempo.

Ou, por fim, você entender a lógica desse objeto e otimiza-lo ou implementar uma lógica diferente para lêr e importar os dados, do arquivo diretamente, sem precisar fazer o uso dessa classe (DOMDocument).

**PS.** Em tempo, ele importa algum registro dessa planilha com 100k registros? Pois pode ser também o tamanho do arquivo, verifica também:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_get('post_max_size', 100M);
```

pois pode ser o tamanho máximo do POST se o arquivo está sendo enviado pelo browser diretamente ou por um FTP direto ao PHP. Tudo isso depende de como está implementado como um todo.

Comment: Respondi o seu comentário ali

Comment: no arquivo lerArquivo.php imprime os valores que estão pré-setados nessas variáveis, pois pode ser que essas diretivas do ini_set estejam desabilitadas

echo ini_set('upload_max_filesize').'<br>';
echo ini_get('post_max_size').'<br>';

Comment: ah, e qual o tamanho desse CSV com 100k linhas.....

Comment: oi, então o problema é esse limite mesmo de memória, não está settando pra 150M o ini_set.
quando eu dou echo no ini get ele fica com 8M. Já testei e pesquisei todas as formas de mudar o tamanho e nenhuma funcionou. 
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '200M');
ini_set('max_input_time', '200M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
set_time_limit(65536);

// o tam do arquivo é 110M e é xml ( não é csv).

Answer (score -2):

Oi, eu fiz as duas implantações que vc sugeriu e mesmo assim não deu certo.
To mostrando o html e o submit para aquela pagina de ler o arquivo

Tentei colocar tanto na primeira pagina quanto na pagina que lê o arquivo e não deu certo
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M'); e
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

```
                    <form id="myform" method="post" action="lerArquivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" style="width:100%;margin-top:2%;margin-right:5px " name="arquivo" />
                        <!-- accept=".csv, .CSV"  -->
                    </form>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onmousedown="lerArquivo()"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i></button>
                </div>

lerArquivo = function() {   

                var arq = document.getElementsByName('arquivo');
                if(arq[0].value == ""){
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Selecione um arquivo',
                        '',
                        'error'
                    );
                } else{
                    $('#myform').submit();
                }

          

            }
```

Answer (score -3):

Tenta colocar no inicio do seu php

eu estava tentando ler um arquivo xlsx de 20 Mega e não ia, nem quando eu apaguei linhas, deixando apenas 10000
achei isto em outro post, que resolveu

ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); //no inicio do php